# Where can I find wsdl.exe for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl

I'm use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 and I want to generate proxy classes from WSDL. I have published WSDL then I save it locally, then use the utility `wsdl.exe`.

Where can I find `wsdl.exe` for Visual Studio 2015?

I found this utility in only one place:

```
C:\Program Files(86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

When I tried to run it not as administrator, I get this message:

```
Visual Studio 2010. Invalid license data. Reinstall is required.
```

After running as administrator the tool works fine and I got my proxy classes.

```
wsdl.exe C:\Applications\SimpleCustomService.wsdl /out:myproxy.cs
```

Is it OK if I use in MS Visual Studio 2015 the wsdl utility, which is included in MS Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have it in:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools`?

Did you try using Developer Command Prompt for VS2015?

Comment: My guess then is that your VS 2015 installation is slightly broken, because I think that this directory should be created during installation.

Comment: From the error it seems that the proxy was generated by an older version of `wsdl.exe` that had different namespaces.
You are right that v10.0A corresponds to a version of windows, but the tools within it are only .NET tools and it should be placed anyway on your machine. The product that creates that folder is called `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 SDK`.